# i want to send file to api url and get the response without redirecting to it using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

the code below is form with action api link
and thats my ajax request

```js
$('#form1').submit(function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.example.com/uploader",
    data: formdata,
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="http://www.example.com/uploader" id="myForm" method="post" name="myForm">
  NDA DOC: <input type="file" name="file1">
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

when i send a file to that api it respond with data i want to get this data without redirecting to it this code in wordpress site

Comment: [e.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add enctype in form tag and use preventDefault to prevent the refresh of page.

You need to serialize the data and send in data.

On the `success` area you need to deal with response.

HTML

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/uploader" id="form1" method="post" name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">   
  NDA DOC: <input type="file" name="file1">
  <input type="submit"  id="submit">
</form>
```

JS

```
 $('#form1').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let data = $( this ).serialize()
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.example.com/uploader",
        data: data,
        success: function(response){
          // success action here
        },
        error: function(response) {
          // error action here
        }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://www.example.com/uploader' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Comment: When you make a Ajax call from a domain outside your API the browsers block this request by security policy. To avoid this you need to return in request response header ```Access-Control-Allow-Origin``` passing the domain or ```'*'``` to allow any domain to request data to api

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the following code to your function in your submit event.

`e.preventDefault();`

because, normally it would submit the form.